# How to use M-O on Emacs in terminal?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs

I bind `M-o` to `next-word`, and want to use `M-O` to shift-select next word.  `M-O` works well on Emacs GUI app on Mac, but not on Emacs in a terminal.

The [reason](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2012-11/msg00503.html) is: In the terminal, `up-arrow` is encoded as `M-O A` (similar for other arrow keys), so `M-O` becomes a prefix key.

A solution is to use timeout, which was implemented by [ergoemacs](https://github.com/ergoemacs/ergoemacs-mode/issues/280).
However, I don't use ergoemacs keymap, so I don't wanna install it yet.  Is there any other (smaller) package/function implemented the timeout solution?

Comment: Why just not use the default `next-word` (actually forward-word) keybinding defined to `M-f`? Are you talking about a different thing?

Comment: Similar to ergoemacs, I re-map almost all shortcuts in my Emacs, e.g., my `M-f` is `forward-char`.

Answer (score 1):

Codes adapted from https://gist.github.com/Pitometsu/f2f68d5e81862ceffb0d76d277376cf1

```
(defun my-tty-init-esc (frame)
  "Update `input-decode-map' in terminal with FRAME."
  (with-selected-frame frame
    (let ((term (frame-terminal frame)))
      (when (not (terminal-parameter term 'my-tty-esc-map))
        (let ((my-tty-esc-map (lookup-key input-decode-map [?\e])))
          (set-terminal-parameter term 'my-tty-esc-map my-tty-esc-map)
          (define-key input-decode-map [?\e]
            `(menu-item "" ,my-tty-esc-map :filter ,#'my-tty-esc))))
      (when (not (terminal-parameter term 'my-tty-M-O-map))
        (let ((my-tty-M-O-map (lookup-key input-decode-map "\eO")))  ; [?\eO] is not valid
          (set-terminal-parameter term 'my-tty-M-O-map my-tty-M-O-map)
          (define-key input-decode-map "\eO"
            `(menu-item "" ,my-tty-M-O-map :filter ,#'my-tty-M-O)))))))
(defun my-tty-esc (map)
  (if (and
       (let ((keys (this-single-command-keys)))
         (and (> (length keys) 0)
              (= (aref keys (1- (length keys))) ?\e)))
       (sit-for my-tty-prefix-timeout))
      (prog1 [escape]
        (when defining-kbd-macro
          (end-kbd-macro)
          (setq last-kbd-macro (vconcat last-kbd-macro [escape]))
          (start-kbd-macro t t)))
    map))
(defun my-tty-M-O (map)
  (if (and
       (let ((keys (this-single-command-keys)))
         (> (length keys) 0))
       (sit-for my-tty-prefix-timeout))
      (progn
        (setq this-command-keys-shift-translated t)
        (handle-shift-selection)
        (next-word)
        )
    map))
(setq my-tty-prefix-timeout 0.01)
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'my-tty-init-esc)
(mapc #'my-tty-init-esc (frame-list))
)
```